# How to get my android options be displayed?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I've just downloaded visual studio 2019. When trying to open Android options, getting this kind of error:"An error occurred trying to load the page.
Unable to create the designer.  File is already opened in an incompatible editor."
How can I fix It. Before my project was loaded in vs2017.
Thanks[image]

Comment: on 17 it works but does not work on 19?

Comment: There may be some problems with your VS2019 installation. It is recommended to reinstall the **Mobile Develop Component** in the visual studio installer. If this is not the case, it is recommended to reinstall VS2019.

Comment: On 17 it works well. I reported bug to Microsoft

Comment: This is twice now I've had something weird like this happen in VS2019.  I've already reinstalled once.

Comment: i have the same problem, reinstalling didn't fix it.

Comment: You can follow this issue from Developer Community:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/515660/cant-open-android-options.html

Comment: @Vitali Hi, now vs2019 this problem should be solved .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I can confirm the issue is NOT solved. I downloaded the latest version of vs2019 last thursday and have had this error since then. Like the OP my original project was initiated in vs2017(enterprise) This is seriously impeding the flow of building and releasing testbuilds for the testers..

Comment: @Vitali Okey , You can show the version number of your VS 2019. I will check it.

Comment: @ Junior Jiang - MSFT. The version number is 16.1.2

Comment: last version of vs2019 and same problem...

Answer (score 1):

> We identified a dependency we recently added for that specific property
>   page which is available in **Window8 or later**.
>
> We already replaced it with an alternative which it's available in
>   Windows7+ so it should be available in the next preview of Visual
>   Studio.
>
> In the meantime, until the fix is available, the workaround would be
>   to **edit the Android Options property page with Visual Studio 2017**
>   or **upgrade the OS**.

[**Source**](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/556619/view.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of re-installing VS2017 just to set some options you can just edit the *.Android.csproj file directly. In my case, I needed to enable MultiDex so I added these two lines in the first PropertyGroup (the one without conditions):

```
<AndroidEnableMultipleDex>true</AndroidEnableMultipleDex>
<AndroidEnableMultiDex>true</AndroidEnableMultiDex>
```

A quick search didn't turn up a complete documentation of all the possible options, unfortunately. In this case I was able to find [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44006261/multidex-xamarin-maps-android-issues) by searching for "csproj multidex".

Answer (score 0):

This is because the incorrect value provided in the property field..
From Visual studio, Unload the project file (.csproj) ..Edith in file with correct property value.

reload the project.
This fixed my issue